# Chart JS: Use function in tooltip template

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have a series of data representing money and I need the tooltip to show the data series and format the data. I have a working function that will convert "123456.78" to "123,456.78" but I cannot apply this in the tooltip. My code is as follows:

```
function formatMoney(n, c, d, t){
  var c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
      d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
      t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
      s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
      i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
      j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
     return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
   };
  var lineChartData = {
        labels : ['January', 'Ferbruary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    datasets : [
      {
        label: "Value",
        fillColor : "rgba(32,78,158,0.2)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(32,78,158,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(32,78,158,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(32,78,158,1)",
        data : ['20000','22000','35000','17000','18000','47500','20000','22000','35000','17000','18000','47500']
      },{
        label: "Budget",
        fillColor: "rgba(47,116,234,0.3)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(47,116,234,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(47,116,234,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(47,116,234,1)",
        data : ['10000','20000','30000','7000','17000','40500','19000','20000','33000','12000','17500','40500']
    },
    ]
  }
  var ctx = document.getElementById("money-graph").getContext("2d");
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> £<%= formatMoney(value,2) %>"
  });
```

The error I'm getting in the console is `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: formatMoney`

I have also tried to define the function as `var formatMoney = function(n, c, d, t)`

Comment: have you tried defining the function the other way, eg, var formatMoney = function(n, c, d, t) ?

Comment: @SamH. yeah and that didn't work either.

Comment: hmmm...
`multiTooltipTemplate: function(chartData){ return chartData.label+" : " + formatMoney(chartData.value, 2); }` ? - maybe the templating can't handle functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making this an answer so it is easier to find for future reference. The problem was the templating engine not being able to handle functions, or something of that nature. But using the other way of templating seems to work:

```
multiTooltipTemplate: function(chartData){
  return chartData.label+" : " + formatMoney(chartData.value, 2);
}
```